# Operational error at cursor when creating function in SQLite

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into my SQLite database, it goes fine until I get the error while creating a function for DB. It sends `OperationalError at cursor`.

I couldn't find solution for my problem.

Code I'm using:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import *

SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT = '''CREATE TABLE password
             (id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,username text, password text, source text)'''
SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT = '''INSERT INTO password (username, password, source)VALUES({},{},{});'''

DATABASE_PATH = 'home/taha/lessons/projects/passStorage/passDB.db'

DATA = dict()


def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        return e

def create_table(connection, sql_commands):
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute(sql_commands)
    print('done')

def get_input():
    USERNAME = input('username: ')
    PASSWORD = input('password: ')
    SOURCE = input('source: ')
    return USERNAME,PASSWORD,SOURCE

def insert_date(connection, data):
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute(SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT.format(data.values))

def main():
    conn = create_connection(DATABASE_PATH)
    create_table(conn, SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT)

    user_info = get_input()
    DATA['username'], DATA['password'], DATA['SOURCE'] = user_info

    insert_date(conn, DATA)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect no error but it sends this:

```
c = connection.cursor()

AttributeError: 'OperationalError' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Comment: Your `create_connection` function returns either a connection or an exception. You never check that return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        return e # <-- here you return OperationalError instance
```

> AttributeError: 'OperationalError' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Shows that OperationalError has no attribute `cursor`

Add additional logic that check connection here.

I believe the core of your problem is wrong file path:

```
DATABASE_PATH = 'home/taha/lessons/projects/passStorage/passDB.db'
```

But I believe should be

```
DATABASE_PATH = '/home/taha/lessons/projects/passStorage/passDB.db'
```